# How to use maven assembly plugin for unix line endings

Tags: maven, unix, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a java project which contains some scripts needed to be deployed on unix machine, for that i need the file endings in unix format, how can i achieve this using maven assembly plugin?

Answer (score 2):

To set the line ending as linux\unix\LF for specific file you can use it lineEnding attribute e.g unix. There are below options are also available:

Sets the line-endings of the files in this fileSet. Valid values:

"keep" - Preserve all line endings

"unix" - Use Unix-style line endings (i.e. "\n")

"lf" - Use a single line-feed line endings (i.e. "\n")

"dos" - Use DOS-/Windows-style line endings (i.e. "\r\n")

"windows" - Use DOS-/Windows-style line endings (i.e. "\r\n")

"crlf" - Use carriage-return, line-feed line endings (i.e. "\r\n")

Example:

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

<id>x</id>
<formats>
    <format>tgz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../../deploy/script/linux_x86</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.version}/bin</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

The maven assembly plgins gives to plenty of option for files. check out the official documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to set encoding and lineending in JAVA_OPTS or MAVEN_OPTS (for Windows):

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dline.endings="\u000A"
```

I have experimented a lot and the only way to change the lineending as commandline paramter is to use unicode. Here you find an explanation, why it is working: https://www.sitepoint.com/java-unicode-mysterious-compile-error/